# 'FileField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden' al querer crear formulario para subir documentos

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Me sale este error en la plantilla que renderiza mi vista, en la cual estoy probando el campo FileField en el modelo.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block Tilte %}
    Registrar Solictud a la Convocatoria
{% endblock Tilte %}

{% block navbar %}
{% endblock navbar %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}  <!--aqui sale el error -->
        <input class="btn btn-default form-control" type="submit" value="Registrar Solicitud">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

mis modelos son:

```
apps/solicitud/models.py

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    if instance.curp:
        filename = "%s.pdf" % instance.curp

    if instance.acta_nacimiento:
        filename = "acta_%s.pdf" % instance.curp

    if instance.comprobante_domicilio:
        filename = "domicilio_%s.pdf" % instance.curp

    if instance.titulo:
        filename = "titulo_%s.pdf" % instance.curp

    return "%s/%s" % (instance.id, filename)


class Solicitud(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=SEXO_CHOICES)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique=True)
    #curpFoto = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

    pais_origen = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="México")
    lugar_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #acta_nacimiento = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

    domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    codigo_postal = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    #comprobante_domicilio = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    escuela_procedencia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    programa_solicitado = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PROGRAMA_SOLICITADO_CHOICES, default=MAS_ADMIN)
    titulado = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=ESTADO_TITULACION_CHOICES, default=YA_TITULADO)
    titulacion_creditos = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TITULACION_CREDITOS_CHOICES, default=NO)
    #titulo = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Solicitud id: {}'.format(self.id)


class Documentacion(models.Model):
    candidato = models.OneToOneField(Solicitud, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    curp = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
```

Tengo comentado los campos del primer modelo para agregarlo hasta que funcione la parte de subir documentos con el modelo de abajo

Mis URLS

```
apps/solicitud/urls.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

import views

app_name = 'solicitud'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'registrar_solicitud/$', views.AddSolicitud.as_view(), name='datos_candidato'),
    url(r'documentacion/$', views.add_documentacion, name='documentos'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Aqui están mis views

```
apps/solicitud/views.py

def add_documentacion(request):
    form = DocumentacionForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    #aqui no sé porque me dice error de que solo recibe un parámetro y que le estoy dando 3

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
       "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "solicitud/solicitud_form.html", context)
```

También agregué a projec/settings.py las variables de MEDIA, MEDIA_URL, STATIC y STATIC_URL

```
project/settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

En mis forms.py están comentados los campos que quiero añadir al modelo solicitud, tengo hecho el de prueba con un solo campo

```
apps/solicitud/forms.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms

from models import Solicitud, Documentacion


class SolicitudForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Solicitud
        fields = [
            'nombre',
            'apellidos',
            'email',

            'fecha_nacimiento',
            #'acta_nacimiento',
            'sexo',
            'curp',
            #'curpFoto',
            'pais_origen',
            'lugar_nacimiento',
            'domicilio',
            #'comprobante_domicilio',
            'codigo_postal',
            'telefono',

            'escuela_procedencia',
            'programa_solicitado',
            'titulado',
            'titulacion_creditos',
            #'titulo',
        ]

        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre(s)',
            'apellidos': 'Apellidos',
            'email': u'Correo Electrónico',
            'fecha_nacimiento': 'Fecha de Nacimiento',
            #'acta_nacimiento': 'Acta de nacimiento',
            'sexo': 'Sexo',
            'curp': 'CURP',
            #'curpFoto': 'Comprobante de la CURP',
            'pais_origen': 'Pais de origen',
            'lugar_nacimiento': 'Lugar de Nacimiento',
            'domicilio': 'Domicilio',
            'codigo_postal': u'Código Postal',
            #'comprobante_domicilio': ' Comprobante de domicilio',
            'telefono': u'Teléfono',

            'escuela_procedencia': 'Escuela de Procedencia',
            'programa_solicitado': 'Programa de Estudios Solicitado',
            'titulado': u'Estado de su Titulación',
            'titulacion_creditos': u'Titulación por créditos de Posgrado',
            #'titulo': u'Título de licenciatura',
        }

        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'apellidos': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'fecha_nacimiento': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            # 'fecha_nacimiento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            # 'acta_nacimiento': forms.FileField(),

            'sexo': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'curp': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            # 'curpFoto': forms.FileField(),

            'pais_origen': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'lugar_nacimiento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'domicilio': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'codigo_postal': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            # 'comprobante_domicilio': forms.FileField(),

            'telefono': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'escuela_procedencia': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'programa_solicitado': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'titulado': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'titulacion_creditos': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            # 'titulo': forms.FileField(),

        }


class DocumentacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documentacion
        fields = ["curp"]

        labels = {
            "curp": u"curp"
        }

        widgets = {
            "curp": forms.FileField()
        }
```

Comment: Hola, ¿y tu formulario cómo lo estás definiendo? Eso es lo más importante ya que es eso lo que está fallando.

Comment: Se me paso agregar mis forms.py, los añado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en esta parte de tu código:

```
class DocumentacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documentacion
        fields = ["curp"]

        labels = {
            "curp": u"curp"
        }

        widgets = {
            "curp": forms.FileField()
        }
```

`FileField` no es un widget (como `Select` o `TextInput`), es un campo. Remueve o comenta esa parte y tu formulario debería funcionar:

```
class DocumentacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documentacion
        fields = ["curp"]

        labels = {
            "curp": u"curp"
        }

        #widgets = {
        #    "curp": forms.FileField()
        #}
```

Ten en cuenta que solo tienes que usar `widgets` dentro del `Meta` cuando quieres reemplazar el widget que Django usa por defecto, o cuando quieres agregar alguna clase CSS para los estilos, por ejemplo.

Dale un vistazo a los campos y a los widgets para que aprendas a diferenciarlos sin confundirlos:

- [Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/)
- [Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/)

Comment: Es que al principio habia formulario que no me los generaba si no indicaba los labels y sus widgets, por cierto, si comento esa sección de código me aparece IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: solicitud_documentacion.candidato_id. ¿Debo mandarle el id en la url y guardar ese id como candidato para guardar en el modelo Documentacion, la relacion de las 2 tablas?

Comment: @Kuroi has puesto que el campo `Documentacion.candidato` no sea nulo, y en tu formulario solo estás poniendo `fields = ['curp']`, es por eso que te sale el error.

Comment: por ese error es que junté los datos en un solo modelo y su formulario, no se como pasar ese atributo y que el usuario no lo tenga que elegir con un select

Comment: @Kuroi lo más sencillo sería que la carga (upload) de la documentación la hagas en una vista aparte, cuando lo hagas supuestamente ya deberías tener el ID del candidato, entonces tu URL sería algo como: `/solicitud/[id]/subir_documentacion`. Incluso podría ser un multi select y luego iterarías por cada archivo y lo guardas para ese candidato.

Comment: si, es lo mejor, así puedo ocultar o deshabilitar campos del formulario si tengo acceso a los otros modelos, y ya no tener que hacer eso con javascript

Comment: ya logré guardar el campo, ahora me resulta otro problema, no me guarda la pk antes de que guarde el documento, quedando así la URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/None/DocumentoA18_ilhyhRA.pdf, además de que lo guarda dañado

Comment: @Kuroi crea otra pregunta con los detalles. No olvides aceptar esta respuesta si te ha servido, así no queda abierta.